# Suppose $H$ is Hamiltonian. Show that $e^H$ must be symplectic.

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

> **Definition/Facts:** Let $K$ denote the skew-symmetric matrix $$\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \end{matrix} \right]. $$ A matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{2n\times 2n}$ is said to be Hamiltonian if $K^{-1}A^TK=-A$ and symplectic if $K^{-1}A^TK = A^{-1}$.

A possible solution is:
$$K^{-1}(e^H)^TK = K^{-1}e^{H^T}K = e^{K^{-1}H^TK} = e^{-H} = (e^H)^{-1}.$$

Thus, $e^H $ is symplectic.

**Question:** How does
$$K^{-1}e^{H^T}K = e^{K^{-1}H^TK}$$

Comment: Try to use the series definition of $e^B$ of a matrix $B$ to show your equality.

Comment: Couldn't you use the fact that $\exp(P^{-1}AP)=P \exp(A) P^{-1}$ when $A$ is diagonal ?

Comment: Do you need $A$ diagonal, @JeanMarie

Comment: @Thomas Andrews You are right, no need. I was focalised on diagonalization operation...

Comment: @ArcticChar, Ah yes, I see the $KK^{-1} = I$ for "$\infty$" many times. That makes sense. Thanks!